# @Transactional(rollbackfor={null}) when creating jar file

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, maven

in my project there are classes containing `@Transactional(rollbackfor=Exception.class)`. When compiling and packaging my project, a jar file is created. However, looking at the `@Transactional(roolbackfor=Exception.class)` classes, I saw `@Transactional(rollbackfor={null})`. What is the reason of that _? And What is the solution ?

Thank you

Comment: Does "looking at" mean inspection of generated classes (e.g. javap) or reflection at runtime?

Comment: yes generated jar file. I am using this jar file into another project.

Comment: ok, thought you're talking about runtime and the exception class isn't on the classpath. But after testing it turned out that this would cause a java.lang.TypeNotPresentException. So long story short: I can't help, sorry.

Comment: Do you directly look at the byte code, or do you use some disassmbler?

Comment: @Ralph no. There is a hibernate dao class. This class contains @Transactional(rollbackfor=Exception.class) after creating jar file containing this class, @Transactional(rollbackfor={null}). When I understand from this problem, somehow compiler ignores Exception.class..

Comment: @Muhammed Yüce: What does "No" mean? How do you look at the jar? Its class files are bytecode (normaly) you can not read them like a text file.

Comment: @Ralph It is very easy.. in Intellij Idea, maven project I created. You can see when you look at the left corner of intellij idea. Thats External Libraries part. To see a jar file inside, simply click + sign. You will understand what I mean if you create a maven project then open in intellij idea.

Comment: @Muhammed Yüce: So you mean you don't have a clue what Intellij shows you: a decompiled source or the sources from the maven repository. -- I asked this because I think it is a problem with the "viewer". Can you somehow upload the class file (not the complete jar) so that I can have a look on it?

Comment: Actually it is not necessary. Thats intellij idea. You can also see the class with @Transactional(rollbackfor={null}), when you extend this class by just clicking the class with @Transactional(rollbackfor={null}) name

Comment: svn checkout http://transactionalproblem.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ transactionalproblem-read-only you can download at this repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the project, but I don't see any problem. When I import the jar in a different project I still see the correct rollback for.

I issued `mvn clean install` on command line to generate the jar. I had a look at your committed jar. Yours looks similar to mine, no problem even with it. I even decompiled it and I can see the `rollbackFor={Exception.class}` in `AzerAuthorityDaoImpl`.